# can not run npm run build/deploy

Tags: reactjs, git, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my application but is not working. 
My package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
"serve": "live-server public --port=8091",
"build": "webpack",
"dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

Error when i run npm run deploy:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Luiz\Desktop\udemy\react-course-projects\indecision-app\build'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! indecision-app@1.0.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the indecision-app@1.0.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: How is `webpack` configured? Does it output to a directory at the root of the project named `build/`? It looks like `serve` expects it to be at `public/`...

Comment: output: {

    path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }

Comment: Then why are you trying to deploy from `build/`? Read the error message: `no such file or directory, stat '...\build'`.

Comment: now it's working, but https://laurabeatris.github.io/indecision/ doesn't show anything

Comment: Check out the Network tab of your browser - it's looking for https://laurabeatris.github.io/bundle.js, but that's a 404 because the bundle is served at https://laurabeatris.github.io/indecision/bundle.js. You'll need to update your Webpack config to make sure it adjusts for this in the links it generates.

Comment: how can i make this work?

Comment: now i'm running "deploy": "gh-pages -d public", isn't supposed to work?

Comment: It *does* work, to a certain extent - it's creating the build and pushing it to the appropriate branch: https://github.com/LauraBeatris/indecision/tree/gh-pages. Now you have to fix the *next* problem, which is covered in the proposed dupe.

Comment: i put 'publicPath: "./public"' in the webpack.config, but still not working

Comment: Looking at that commit, `index.html` **didn't change**, so you shouldn't really have expected that to start working. You need it to be looking for the bundle in the right place [when it loads it](https://github.com/LauraBeatris/indecision/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L12). I'd recommend doing more research to understand what the problem is and how to fix it - I've retracted that dupe suggestion, but it will be in the Webpack config somewhere.

Comment: thankssss, i changed the path in the html to /public/bundle.js and now it's working. i'm a beginner so sorry for the noob questions

Comment: But you need to make that part of the build, or it'll break again next time.

Comment: now when i try to run "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server" it's not working

Comment: i changed the path to  path: path.join(__dirname, "public/bundle.js")

Comment: I am facing the same problem, can you explain how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You have to include, link of you github page also as homepage property.

Like this
`"homepage": "<link of you github page for this project>"`.

Example:
`"homepage": "https://hsnice16.github.io/4kids/"`